# How to show list in ng2-smart-table cell?

Tags: angular

I have this settings for ng2-smart-table and I can't show the list of users in table Like in  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOSi3.png)

```
  settings = {
    columns: {
      users: {
        title: 'User',
        filter: {
          type: 'list',
          config: {
            selectText: 'Select...',
            list: [
              { value: 'Glenna Reichert', title: 'Glenna Reichert' },
              { value: 'Kurtis Weissnat', title: 'Kurtis Weissnat' },
              { value: 'Chelsey Dietrich', title: 'Chelsey Dietrich' },
            ],
          },
        },
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this. I hope it works :

```
          settings = {
            columns: {
              users: {
                title: 'User',
                filter: {
                  type: 'list',
                  config: {
                    selectText: 'Select...',
                    list: [
                      { value: 'Glenna Reichert', title: 'Glenna Reichert' },
                      { value: 'Kurtis Weissnat', title: 'Kurtis Weissnat' },
                      { value: 'Chelsey Dietrich', title: 'Chelsey Dietrich' },
                    ],
                  },
                },
                width: '250px',
                type: 'list',
                editor: {
                  type: 'list',
                  config: {                  
                    list: [
                      { value: 'Glenna Reichert', title: 'Glenna Reichert' },
                      { value: 'Kurtis Weissnat', title: 'Kurtis Weissnat' },
                      { value: 'Chelsey Dietrich', title: 'Chelsey Dietrich' },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).